# Is this gif from a movie, and from which?

Tags: story-identification, horror

I was going around the Internet and found this gif. I'd like to know if it's from a movie, and if so, from which one?

[image: http://i.giphy.com/5xaOcLFTwq98FtkPT7G.gif]

Comment: I could easily be wrong, but it looks too cheesy to be from a real movie.  It looks more like something that someone threw together at home with a weird Halloween decoration or something.  The girl in bed doesn't seem to know what "acting" means, and she almost appears to be enjoying being eaten by a witch-thing with an enormous head.

Comment: A reverse image search on this gets a lot of hits, in which I can't find an attribution. If this is from a movie, it is likely an obscure movie.

Answer (score 19):

It's not from a movie, but rather from a haunted house created for 2011 Halloween Horror Nights at Universal Studios Hollywood, go to around 3:08 in this video:

(found it by doing a reverse image search on the gif along with the search term "movie", which took me to [this metafilter thread](http://ask.metafilter.com/254239/Anybody-know-what-movie-this-is-from) where someone identified it)

Comment: Note to the "actress" in this video:  For future reference, when you're supposed to be pretending to get eaten by a monster, you probably shouldn't be smiling and looking directly at the camera.

Comment: @WadCheber What if the point is to have a good time? Like when we were young and sang Silverstein's "I'm Being Eaten By A Boa Constricter?" :)