# Can someone identify the source of this photo of a creature swallowing a woman laying on a bed?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I just found this photo and I wanted to see where it came from.

[image]

Comment: https://gamingshogun.com/2011/10/01/halloween-horror-nights-review-2011/ ==> https://gamingshogun.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/hhn2011opennight-1891.jpg

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal's_Halloween_Horror_Nights

Comment: It sounds like an "Halloween-themed event", but I'm not entirely sure of the context in which that picture can be seen, so I won't post an answer.

Comment: https://youtu.be/PARg0XkG-rA?t=184

Answer (score 8):

It's a picture of an actress getting "eaten" by an animatronic, from [Gaming Shogun's review](https://gamingshogun.com/2011/10/01/halloween-horror-nights-review-2011/) of Halloween Horror Nights 2011 at Universal Studios Hollywood. The specific attraction is [La Llorona: Villa de Almas Perdidas](https://halloweenhorrornights.fandom.com/wiki/La_Llorona:_Villa_de_Almas_Perdidas).

See 4:00 in the video below:

Or 3:03 in this video:

Comment: Another view here (with the right lighting): https://youtu.be/PARg0XkG-rA?t=189

Comment: Unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102587/is-this-gif-from-a-movie-and-from-which/102588#102588 (thought this looked familiar)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots This is a situation that I've always thought about hypothetically. The rules were designed for ID questions about people's blurry memories where we can't always determine if two stories are the same without confirmation. Do we still have to follow those rules when they ask about a blurry photograph and we *can* determine two questions are exactly the same?

Comment: @Laurel I do remember edge cases for which we can tell it's a duplicate even without asker's confirmation (such as this case for example). I think some of them were closed as duplicates

Comment: @Laurel That makes sense to me.